# VBA Getting a date variable always 3 months in the future

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a way to get VBA to calculate a date 3 months in the future from the current date of the system (also as the 1st day of that future month).

This would be then used in filter below.

```
Workbooks(FN1).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Final1).AutoFilter Field:=18, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "9/1/2017")
```

Basically what I need is to replace the **"9/1/2017"** with a variable that gets calculated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT:** Used below code in the end which works great. However, I just found out a problem which makes it a bit more complicated.

```
Workbooks(FN1).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Res).AutoFilter Field:=18, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 3, 1))
```

Seems like the filter needs to be set on multiple years, not just the current year. Recorded, it looks like this.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$X$2767").AutoFilter Field:=18, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "9/1/2021", 1, "9/1/2020", 1, "9/1/2019", 1, _
    "9/1/2018", 1, "9/1/2017", 1, "9/1/2016", 1, "9/1/2015", 1, "9/1/2014", 1, "9/1/2013")
```

Problem is, the years will be variable as well (ex: Might not have 2013 in the data source next month but 2022 might be added). 
So problem gets more complicated as now I would need something that checks every year in the data source `Range(Res).Column("R")` and, I assume, would loop through all the years and check the 1st day of the month 3 months in the future.

Or rather is it possible to filter just on the month? So it just picks September (in this case) across all years?

Comment: What date are you expecting from the calculated variable?

Comment: Not sure I get your question. I need the variable so I can then use it in the code above instead of the typed in date. So whenever I run the code it would check what date is today, add 3 months to it and set it on the 1st day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly like:

**Edit1:** Based on your comment.

```
Criteria2:=Array(1, Format(DateAdd("m", 3, Date) - DatePart("d", Date) + 1, "m/d/yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to use `DateSerial` which returns a date given a specified year, month and day:

`DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 3, 1)`

Comment: Oh nice, this looks much more easier to read and works the same. Thanks a lot Darren

Comment: Its useful for returning the last day of the month as well `DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 4, 0)` returns day 0 of the following month which is effectively the last day of the previous month.

Comment: I've edited my question as apparently my initial assumption was incorrect (that it would be applied just for current year). Not sure what would be the easiest solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to get the date of the first of the month (that is 3 months from now) automatically. For that, you can use a combination of `DateAdd` and `DateAdd` function:

```
Dim myFirstoftheMonth As Date

myFirstoftheMonth = DateAdd("d", 1, WorksheetFunction.DateAdd(Date, 2))
```

afterwards, you can replace your hard-coded `"9/1/2017"` with `myFirstoftheMonth` in your Filter.

Comment: Thank you, will keep it in mind if I want to have the variable declared outside of the filter, for now I've used @L42 's solution.